react native gifted chart pie chart focusOnPress not working
I'm trying to use a pie chart from react-native-gifted-charts. I'd like to show an image related to the selected pie chart value. When I deploy a code like below, it works find to toggle the image yet focusOnPress doesn't work anymore but blinks as if I clicked the chart twice. However, when I replace the onPress function with something simple as console.log(item), focusOnPress works perfectly fine as expected. Did anyone encounter a similar issue?
                    <PieChart
                        radius={100}
                        focusOnPress
                        data={pieChartData}
                        extraRadiusForFocused={5}
                        onPress={(item) => setIsPieChartSelected(!isPieChartSelected)}
                    />
                    {isPieChartSelected && <MyImage />}


In your example, the focus is not working properly when used along with the onPress prop.
This is because you are updating the state in the onPress event (through setIsPieChartSelected). This results in a re-render of the entire chart and resetting of the focused index.
You can avoid resetting of the focused index by making the pieChartData a state variable and updating the focused property in the pieChartData in the onPress event.
Basically, your onPress callback should have the below code-
onPress={
  (item,index) => {
    setIsPieChartSelected(!isPieChartSelected);
    setPieChartData([...pieChartData].map((item, ind) => ({...item, focused: 
    ind===index}))
  )
};

This answer to an issue in the repo might be helpful.
